# EntityFramework - Composite keys and foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

Im working on a project and I'm using Entity Framework with the code first approach. My first model, Player, has two string for its ids (I didnt choose that and I know its a bad approach) :

```
public class Player()
{

    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public string Name { get; set;}

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public string TeamId { get; set;}

    public Stat PlayerStat { get; set;}
}
```

The class Stat :

```
public class Stat()
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set;}

    // This property should set the name id of the player
    public string Name { get; set;}

    // This property should set the teamId of the player
    public string TeamId{ get; set;}

    [Required]
    public Player Player { get; set;}
}
```

The player class has a one-to-one relationship with the class stat, where the Stat class is optional to he player class, but the player class is required for the stat class.

My problem is, when I create a new migration with Entity Framework and I update the database, it creates 5 columns for the Stat table.

- Id
- Name
- TeamId
- Player_Name
- Player_TeamId

The properties Name and TeamId in the class stat should only be there to set the values of the foreign keys, and should not create columns in the table. Is there a way to map the property Name to the generated column "Player_Name" and TeamId to "Player_TeamId" ?

Comment: you need to manually create your foreign keys to each table.  Those object references cant work unless you have an ID column to hold that reference.  EF is trying to create that for you since you didnt specify one.  You have a team_id but you havent told EF that its your foreign key.  You can do this very easily if you use the EF designer with quick drag and drop.  You dont have a player_id in your stat table that points to the parent player

Comment: Player name as a part of the primary key - it's "cruel" :)

Comment: It is indeed haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference your foreign keys in the Stat class:

```
[ForeignKey("Player")]
public string Name { get; set;}

[ForeignKey("Player")]
public string TeamId { get; set;}
```

Comment: When I try to add the attribute to the property like this : `[ForeignKey("Player"), Column(Order = 1)]`, I get this error : **Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.**

Comment: Okay I think I got it, I deleted the id property in the class stat, and I added the key attribute to both of my foreign keys. Thank you for the help !